# An alternative means to charge my lap top

Tags: laptop, battery

The battery in my lap top will not charge at all using a regular charger.  When I plug the charger in nothing happens. Once the battery life runs out I will no longer be able to use the lap top. Is there an alternative way to charge the battery?

I bought a new charger. Nothing happens when I plug it in. This is what happened that caused the problem. My kid stuck a pencil in the hole where you plug in the charger. Afterwards when I plugged the charger back in that corner part got hot. I unplugged the charger and the tip was smoking.Ever since then nothing happens when I plug in a charger. I even bought a universal and that did not worrk either. The charger is good because it works on my other lap top.

Comment: I bought a new charger.  Nothing happens when I plug it in.  This is what happened that caused the problem.  My kid stuck a pencil in the hole where you plug in the charger.  Afterwards when I plugged the charger back in that corner part got hot.  I unplugged the charger and the tip was smoking.Ever since then nothing happens when I plug in a charger.  I even bought a universal and that did not worrk either.  The charger is good because it works on my other lap top.

Comment: It sounds like the pencil lead shorted the socket.  Try to look inside it and clean it out with the battery removed and the laptop shut off.  Try blasting it with canned air.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your charger socket.Go to someone who can fix it and don't try plugging a charger.